# Getting java.lang.IllegalStateException while calling a method JobRequest.Builder.schedule()

Tags: java, android, singleton, job-scheduling, illegalstateexception

I want to use an android job to schedule a job. I have checked the sample of this which works fine.

When I tried to add an android job in my app and called the method is getting crash with illegal state exception.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.siddhi.creditOneField/com.example.siddhi.creditOneField.Activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to call create() at least once to create the singleton
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to call create() at least once to create the singleton
at com.evernote.android.job.JobManager.instance(JobManager.java:166)
at com.evernote.android.job.JobRequest$Builder.<init>(JobRequest.java:485)
at com.example.siddhi.creditOneField.Activities.TrackingJob.schedulePeriodic(TrackingJob.java:31)
at com.example.siddhi.creditOneField.Activities.MainActivity.setUpUI(MainActivity.java:164)
at com.example.siddhi.creditOneField.Activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:105)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6672)
```

This is the exception I am getting.

Main Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setUpUI();
}
public void setUpUI()
{
    TrackingJob.schedulePeriodic();
}
```

Tracking Job :

```
class TrackingJob extends Job {

    static final String TAG = "tracking";

    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected Result onRunJob(Params params) {

        Intent pi = new Intent(getContext(), GetLocationService.class);

        getContext().startService(pi);

        return Result.SUCCESS;
    }

    static void schedulePeriodic() {
        new JobRequest.Builder(TrackingJob.TAG)
                .setPeriodic(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(15), TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(15))
                .setUpdateCurrent(true)
                .setPersisted(true)
                .build()
                .schedule();
    }
}
```

In sample app its called same way and works fine in that, why is it crashing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create object of `TrackingJob` using below code

```
  class DemoJobCreator implements JobCreator {

        @Override
        public Job create(String tag) {
            switch (tag) {
                case TrackingJob.TAG:
                    return new TrackingJob ();
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Application Class

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        JobManager.create(this).addJobCreator(new DemoJobCreator());
    }
}
```

It will create object of your job class,then you can add schedule it.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setUpUI();
}
public void setUpUI()
{
    TrackingJob.schedulePeriodic();
}
```

Comment: how to call schedule periodic?

Comment: Its not creating the job, not going into the Tracking Job

Comment: same as you did there is no change for call `schedulePeriodic`

Comment: Thanx it worked. but do you have any idea that android job works on every OS or not? because in red mi I tried sample app with notifications I got only whenever I open the app and in moto g4 plus I got notifications in every 15 minutes. dose it work on red mi or not?